# Linux script to generate a list of urls from a list of authors

Tags: linux, printf, text-processing, xargs

I need to take a list of authors names of which may consist from 1 to 4 words like this

1. Osho
2. Hartmann Nicolai
3. Bird Robert Montgomery
4. Coates Ta-Nehisi

   and generate URLs like this

site.com/word1+word+word3+word4

If I do it like this `<list.txt xargs -l | xargs printf '"site.com/%s\n' >url.txt` it will accept one word.
My question is how do I add 3 more optional parameters like "%s"?
Or maybe there are easier ways with other commands?

Comment: `sed 's,^ *,,;s, *$,,;s,  *,+,g;s,^,site.com/,' <list.txt >url.txt`

Comment: didnt work
from Achebe Chinua it made site.com/+A+c+h+e+b+e+C+h+i+n+u+a+

Comment: Seems to be a typo in third `s` command: `sed 's/^ *//;s, *$,,;s, \+,+,g;s,^,site.com/,' <list.txt > url.txt` (`*` became a `\+`)

Comment: yes now it works
thank you!

Comment: my third s is supposed to be <space><space><star>, not <space><star>